# Plot a signal moving average crossover in pine language

Tags: pine-script

I'm using a script wrote here by AnyDozer (great).
My question: how to add ability to plot "arrow up and down" when the crossover occur.
Thanks in advance for help!
Giancarlo

Comment: What is the script called?

Comment: WMA Ely , period 16, offset +1